# Rails- adding comments with showing edited features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Im creating a simple rails App which has a comments, when Im editing a comment,it should be shown as "Edited" to others..Ive searched a lot ,but can't find the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably compare the `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps of the comment record. They should be equal for a comment that has not been edited.

Comment: nope.It should be shown as "Edited" next to the bottom of that comment.. ex: facebook comments..if I edit any one of my comments, it should be shown as "edited' to others..anyway Thanks dude..can u help me more?

Comment: Basically, if the Comment is saved after it has been created, the `updated_at` timestamp gets assigned a new value. You can just put the 'Edited' - Statement into the view with an if-statement checking that condition.